# famo.us + angularjs for production?

Tags: angularjs, famo.us, famous-angular

AngularJS is working on v2.0 which is the breaking change, and NOT backward compatible. If developing famo.us+ angularjs now is there any migration path for it?

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today [Famo.us](http://famo.us) and [Famous-Angular](https://famo.us/integrations/angular/#/intro) are still in beta and the Famo.us library engine is getting a re-write in private to be released sometime in 2015.  You would have to be the judge of whether/when it is ready for production.

Early stage Famous-Angular was developed by [Thomas Street](http://thomasstreet.com).  The best reference for famous-angular is [Famo.us](https://famo.us/integrations/angular/#/intro)

You should follow them on Github

- [Famo.us repository](https://github.com/Famous/famous)
- [Famous-Angular repository](https://github.com/Famous/famous-angular)
- [Famous-Angular roadmap](https://www.pivotaltracker.com/n/projects/1119890)